# swift 4, how do I load over 3000~ pictures in collectionView?

Tags: swift, collectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` for an album.
I got the picture to load on iPhone 7. I got it to load about 2000 pictures but if there are over 3000 pictures when I scroll the `UICollectionView` down it is very slow and some times the app stops.

I am using this code to get the pictures.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func fetchImage(asset: PHAsset, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, targetSize: CGSize) {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        options.isSynchronous = true
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: contentMode, options: options) { image, _ in
            guard let image = image else { return }
            switch contentMode {
            case .aspectFill:
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            case .aspectFit:
                self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            }
            self.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

and I made a `let imageCache = NSCache<NSIndexPath, UIImage>()`
and used it in the `cellForItem`. but that didn't help this problem.
is there any other way to do this?

and also I am getting 3 picture a row and the size of `self.view.frame.width / 2`

If there is no way. Do I have to get a smaller size of the image?

`cellForItem` code:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSIndexPath, UIImage>()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "albumCell", for: indexPath) as? AlbumCollectionViewCell

    let asset: PHAsset? = AlbumModel.allPhotos?.object(at: indexPath.row)

    cell!.albumImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    if let fromImageCache = imageCache.object(forKey: indexPath as NSIndexPath) {
        cell!.albumImageView.image = fromImageCache
        return cell!
    }

    let setSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 2, height: view.frame.width / 2)
    cell!.albumImageView.fetchImage(asset: asset!, contentMode: .aspectFill, targetSize: setSize)

    imageCache.setObject(cell!.albumImageView.image!, forKey: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Can you show the collectionview code?

Comment: @CerlinBoss Updated.

Comment: "options.isSynchronous = true" I don't think that's a good idea, that's slowing your UI, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tips to improve performance when scrolling through the photo library:

Don't implement your own image cache or use the default image manager, use your own instance of `PHCachingImageManager`. You can tell it to start caching images surrounding your scroll position to improve performance.

Don't use synchronous fetching of images. Use the asynchronous methods and update the image view in the completion block, though note that the completion block can fire before the fetch method has even returned, and fire multiple times as you get better quality images out of the library.

Cancel fetches as your cells go off screen.

I haven't worked with the framework for a while, but I wrote up some notes about it [here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2015/07/14/things-i-learnt-about-the-photos-framework/) which are hopefully still relevant.

Comment: https://github.com/ayakix/Image-Picker/blob/master/Demo/Image-Picker/ImagePickerViewController.swift
I used this code and stopCachingImages calls. but the Phone memory goes up, up, up. 
is this code the good way to do this?

Comment: Using a lot of memory is fine, as long as it goes away again. However the code you link to isn't very good; it adds a new image view every time a photo is fetched from the library, so after a while of scrolling you will have hundreds of image views stacked in the cell, which will consume a lot of memory. It also doesn't deal with the asynchronous nature of the fetch image call, since the completion block could be executed after the cell has been reused and it should be displaying a different image.

Comment: imageManager.requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: setSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: options) { (image, info) -> Void in
                cell!.albumImageView.image = image
        }
I used the code like this. but the memory still dosn't go away after scrolling.. no ideas?

Comment: when I use the first code I wrote with options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.resizeMode = .fast this options. the memory only goes up to 200mb for 8000 pictures. but when I use PHCachingImageManager the memory dosen't go away and goes up to 800mb. but is this a better way then the first code I wrote?

Comment: You're caching thousands of images, that's going to use memory. The memory use should drop if your device receives a memory warning. But it's up to you to decide on where to compromise between performance and memory use.

Answer (score 0):

if you load 3000 pictures at a stretch it will cause **memory issue** **app will get terminated** that why app stops better you can use pagination to load 3000 pictures in CollectionView

Comment: So. I have to load the pictures only 500 photos once a time? But when I do that when the memory haves over 3000~4000 photos init it will not get slow and crash?

Comment: No why you want to load 500 pictures at a time, In your device Approximately 50 pictures on grid based style so at a time get 50 pictures using pagination then it wont crash or will not be slow